# Backbone models and URL exceptions

Tags: javascript, api, rest, backbone.js

I have a Backbone model called `User` which has a `urlRoot` of `/api/users`. Thus, if I create a new model with an ID of 5, the url will be `/api/users/5`.

I have also implemented another endpoint which is to get an individual user's Twitter friends. The endpoint for this is `/api/users/:id/twitter-friends`

Do I need to create a new collection with this `url`, and manually set the `id`, or can I somehow create a method on my model which will make this request and return a new collection instance (of that user's Twitter friends). For example:

```
var user = new User({ id: 5 })
user.findTwitterFriends() // returns collection of users
```

Or, make a unique collection for data of this sort:

```
var user = new User({ id: 5 })

var users = new Users()
users.url = user.url() + '/find-friends/twitter' // /api/users/5/find-friends/twitter
users.fetch()
```

What is the best practice for dealing with URLs in this way? Is there a better way? I have similar needs for other uses, such as my API endpoint that can get users by their username at `/api/users/username/:username`. For this I am having to manually set the urlRoot:

```
var user = new User({ username: username })
user.urlRoot = user.urlRoot + '/username/' + username
user.fetch()
```

Perhaps I should design my URLs differently? I'm open to all suggestions.

Comment: Why not add the Users collection as a field inside User? That way , you can keep the id of the parent User as a field in the collection and generate the url like this (inside the collection): `url:function() { return '/api/users/'+this.parentUser.id+'/twitter-friends'; }`

Comment: BTW, BackboneRelational maintains these kinds of relations , I personally use it a lot and recommend it for these kinds of scenarios

Comment: I like more your first option, you could also return a Promise object instead of a collection of friends, anyone knows which one is better?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the best way it to override Backbone.sync, even in the model.

Looking at [Backbone Model.fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch)! you can see that it takes [options] .
So from the top of my head I would say this would be a cleaner way. you could even only override the Backbone sync with your get user, and let Backbone handle the getUsers.

```
/*
this method is redundant.I added it to show you can add options as you go. 
*/

getUsers : function() {
    this.fetch({
        action = 'getUsers';
    });
}



getUser : function(username) {
    this.fetch({
        action = 'getSingleUser'.
        username = username;
    });
},

sync : function(method, model, options) {

        if(method === 'read'){
            if(options.action === 'getSingleUser') {
                                this.url = '/username/' + options.username;
                            }
            else this.url = '/find-friends/twitter';
            ret = Backbone.sync.apply(this, arguments);
            return ret;
        }
        else{
            return Backbone.sync.call(this, method, this, options);
        }
}
```